# 'MongoCursor' not found in Doctrine/Bundle/MongoDBBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php

Tags: symfony, doctrine, phpunit, symfony-2.1, php-mongodb

I am writing some unit tests for some services I have on my Symfony2 project. I need to access the services via the service container and I am using this approach:

```
class DummyTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
   protected static $kernel;
   protected static $container;

   public static function setUpBeforeClass()
   {
      self::$kernel = new \AppKernel('test', true);
      self::$kernel->boot();
      self::$container = self::$kernel->getContainer();
   }

  //test cases
}
```

When *$kernel->boot()* is called I get the following error: *'MongoCursor' not found in Doctrine/Bundle/MongoDBBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php*. I looked into the Configuration.php and there was no reference to *MongoCursor*. Is this a Bundle's version problem?

**Environment**: 
 *Symfony2.1.6* and *DoctrineMongoDBundle's version 2.0.1*.

Comment: I was using a php version that did not have the necessary modules.

    php54 phpunit -c <folder>

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem because of a silly mistake - I haven't enabled mongodb extension.